# Flutter TabBar: Update tab (stateful widget) everytime a tab gets visible

Tags: flutter

happy new year! :)

I have three tabs, each holding a stateful widget. The data presented in tab #2 could be changed by the user within tab #3. Thus, when moving back from tab #3 to tab #2, I need to call an update() method within tab #2. Is there a stateful widget method that gets fired everytime the widget gets visible? If not, what opporutinites do I have in order to achieve this?

Best, Nico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not updating is due to the widget already been rendered and now cached until the user exits the app. You can try numerous methods to make this work. For example, `VoidCallBack` method, adding an async function or leaving a blank `setState` in the initState itself. At the end of the day, it depends on how your app works. If you have a custom tabbar I'd recommend using the `VoidCallBack` method or maybe adding an `async` function which will be called before you return a render. Regardless these methods should work.